# Can you determine a static position in space, using a light clock?

Tags: time-dilation

I know, most of you will now say you can't determine what is a static position in space, or in other words velocity of an object relative to the space itself.

But listen now. Imagine a time clock. One on Earth, one on a space ship. Space ship and Earth moving at the same speed in the same direction. Now both clock are ticking at exactly same speed. If the space ship slows down, the clock on board will start ticking faster. Now the ship slows down even more, the clock starts ticking even faster. But there is a point, where the ship isn't going in the same direction as the Earth anymore, because it slowed down to a complete halt, and started to move in the  opposite direction. So now the clock onboard slows down again, as velocity is now not 0. Now if there was a way for people on Earth observe the other clock and compare the ticking to theirs, could they tell the point where the space ship clock was fastest, and that was the stationary position relative to space?

I will be glad for any reply, as this is a bug in my head. I am not a scientist, I am just interested in time dilation. I am sure there is an explanation why this won't work, but I can't think of it.

Comment: There is no static position in space.  All you can do is measure your position relative to another object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. From the text it looks like you're just asking if you can measure something's velocity with respect to Earth.

Answer (score 2):

> Space ship and Earth moving at the same speed in the same direction.

Another way to say this is that they are at rest relative to each other.

> Now both clock are ticking at exactly same speed.

All observers will agree that the two clocks tick at the same rate and continue to do so.

> If the space ship slows down, the clock on board will start ticking faster.

Via what mechanism would you determine the clock to be "ticking faster"?

Since the two observers are no longer at rest relative to each other, they don't agree on the clock speeds or even which one is faster.

As the spaceship changed speed, the people onboard now think the Earth clocks are ticking *slower* than the spaceship clock.

But the people on Earth now think they are ticking *faster* than the spaceship clock.  The greater the difference in velocity between the two, the greater this discrepancy.

As the ship continues to change speed, there's no point at which either the occupants or the observers on Earth find the ship's clock to be at some special rate.

Answer (score 1):

> Space ship and Earth moving at the same speed in the same direction.

As @BowlOfRed said, we describe that condition by saying that the space ship and the Earth are at rest with respect to each other. People on Earth think the space ship is not moving, and vice versa.

> If the space ship slows down...

It *can't* slow down. Your starting condition is that, from Earth's point of view (i.e., *relative** to Earth), the ship is not moving. It can't go any slower than that. If the ship accelerates in *any* direction, it's speeding up relative to Earth, not slowing down.

---

* If "relative" sounds like "relativity," that's not a coincidence. You're hoping to use ideas from the theory of relativity to define absolute space, but one of the *postulates* of relativity (i.e., one of the foundational ideas upon which the theory is built) is that there is *no* "absolute space." We can only define the position and motion of any given thing *relative to* some other thing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve all these STR paradoxes is to understand that there is no absolute point of view where "one clock is faster than another". Everything is relative and you always need to specify where are you looking at clocks. In twin paradox from earth POV spaceship's clocks are slower, from spaceship's view earth's clock are slower. Measuring the "the speed of one clock relative to another" is like measuring what runner is faster in the stadium and it requires simultaneous measuring their positions. But simultanious things from one POV are not simultaneous from another.
And there will be always a system that moves with average velocity of two objects, where clocks of both objects would go with the same speed, but this system is not some unique for all pairs of objects in universe